# How do I grab status updates from a facebook group?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, facebook

I'm making a website for a organization that also has a  facebook  group, and keeps it pretty up to date.... So, I was wondering if there was a way to pull the 5 most recent posts. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Faceook Javascript SDK to make a request to the graph api. For example:

```
FB.api('/{groupId}/feed', function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

This does however assume that the user viewing the page has access to the group feed. If you want to display the information to everybody you are probably going to have to do that on the server using an access token associated with an account that has access to the facebook group date. However, keep in mind that displaying a group feed to the public may be a violation of facebook's terms, I am not sure though so you'll have to read about that.

See this link for the reference on the graph api group feed call. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group